Why dir -Force -r >$null returns "System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand" exception on my USB pendrive
Why does dir -Force -Recurse >$null return System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand exception on my USB pendrive.
I first did a chkdsk e: /x /r and then I tried this :
PS E:\> dir -Force -Recurse >$null
dir : The system cannot find the file specified
At line:1 char:1
+ dir -Force -r >$null
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-ChildItem], Win32Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand

PS E:\>

I expect the dir to continue until the end without the stdout being mingled with the list of all the files.
EDIT0 : Adding -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue still show the error message somehow :
PS E:\> dir -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -r >$null
dir : The system cannot find the file specified
At line:1 char:1
+ dir -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -r >$null
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-ChildItem], Win32Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand

PS E:\>


you're redirecting all stdout to null what did you expect? seems like you want to redirect errors to null in which case it would be 2>$null but also use -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue instead.

what is the result of NOT redirecting the output to $null?

@sirtao I redirected to $null to be able to see the error message or else it would have been mingled with the list of all the files in my pendrive.

is the list missing some files? From the error message I suspect there might be a file with a name that Get-ChildItem doesn't like

@sirtao In fact, I'm trying to understand why this code fails with the same exception on my pendrive dir -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -r $dirName 2>$null | ? Length -gt 1mb | select fullname,length | sort Length -Descending. Shall I need to post another question for that ?

might just be that Get-ChildItem doesn't know how to traverse usb drives? I'm not sure, don't have one for testing
